# Get email address from OAuth token Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, token, owin, claims-based-identity

I am using `OAuth` security in my `Asp.net MVC` Web API. I am adding an email address and password in `ClaimsIdentity` to generate the token. It is working fine as expected.
Now, to get that user data, I want to convert token to email address and get data based on it. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your action

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public void Test()
    {
        string email = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(<EMAIL_CLAIM_TYPE>).Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have only `Token` in a header as `Bearer token_value`. So, will this work?

Comment: yes, that's the way it works and also you need to have BearerAuthentication middleware in your owin pipeline to convert `token_value` to claims